# How do I export trajectory data in LidarView while its running live (using the Sensor Stream)?

Tags: paraview, lidar

Im using LidarView to run SLAM on my lidar. I use the sensor stream to view my lidar and use the SLAM (Online) filter to run SLAM. However, I want to be able to extract the trajectory data while it's running live. Currently I can only see an option to export the data after it's finished running.